# ARKit add reference images from url

Tags: ios, swift, arkit, image-recognition

I want to add ARReferenceImages from a server. For this I get an array with the URL's to the images. T tried with the following function, that iterates the url's and adds the new created ARImages to the set. But it does not work.

```
    func addReferences(media: NSArray){
    var customReferenceSet = Set<ARReferenceImage>()
    for medium in media{
        let type = (medium as AnyObject).value(forKey: "type");
        let t = type as! String

        let reference = (medium as AnyObject).value(forKey: "reference");
        let ref = reference as! String


        let ide = (medium as AnyObject).value(forKey: "id");
        let id = ide as! String


        let url = URL(string: ref)
        let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)


        let downloadPicTask = session.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in

            if let e = error {
                print("Error downloading picture: \(e)")
            } else {

                if let res = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
                    print("Downloaded picture with response code \(res.statusCode)")
                    if let imageData = data {
                        let image = UIImage(data: imageData)!
                        let imageToCIImage = CIImage(image: image)
                        let cgImage = self.convertCIImageToCGImage(inputImage: imageToCIImage!)
                        let arImage = ARReferenceImage(cgImage!, orientation: CGImagePropertyOrientation.up, physicalWidth: 0.2)
                        arImage.name = id
                        customReferenceSet.insert(arImage)
                    } else {
                        print("Couldn't get image: Image is nil")
                    }
                } else {
                    print("Couldn't get response code for some reason")
                }
            }
        }

        downloadPicTask.resume()
    }

    self.configuration = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
    self.configuration?.detectionImages = customReferenceSet
    sceneView.session.run(configuration!)
}
```

Sometimes, but not everytime, I get the following output:

[boringssl_session_read] SSL_ERROR_ZERO_RETURN(6): operation failed because the connection was cleanly shut down with a close_notify alert

Some ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you set `detectionImages` before the async network requests could actually fetch the images, meaning that you actually assign the empty set to `detectionImages`.

You need to make sure that you only set `detectionImages` once all images were fetched from the server, which you can achieve by using a `DispatchGroup`.

```
func addReferences(media: NSArray){
    var customReferenceSet = Set<ARReferenceImage>()
    let imageFetchingGroup = DispatchGroup()
    for medium in media { 
        let type = (medium as AnyObject).value(forKey: "type");
        let t = type as! String

        let reference = (medium as AnyObject).value(forKey: "reference");
        let ref = reference as! String

        let ide = (medium as AnyObject).value(forKey: "id");
        let id = ide as! String

        let url = URL(string: ref)
        let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)

        imageFetchingGroup.enter()
        let downloadPicTask = session.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in
            if let e = error {
                print("Error downloading picture: \(e)")
                imageFetchingGroup.leave()
            } else {
                if let res = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
                    print("Downloaded picture with response code \(res.statusCode)")
                    if let imageData = data {
                        let image = UIImage(data: imageData)!
                        let arImage = ARReferenceImage(image.cgImage!, orientation: CGImagePropertyOrientation.up, physicalWidth: 0.2)
                        arImage.name = id
                        customReferenceSet.insert(arImage)
                        imageFetchingGroup.leave()
                    } else {
                        print("Couldn't get image: Image is nil")
                        imageFetchingGroup.leave()
                    }
                } else {
                    print("Couldn't get response code for some reason")
                    imageFetchingGroup.leave()
                }
            }
        }

        downloadPicTask.resume()
    }

    self.configuration = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
    imageFetchingGroup.notify(queue: .main) {
        self.configuration?.detectionImages = customReferenceSet
        sceneView.session.run(configuration!)
    }
}
```

You also shouldn't use `NSArray` in Swift and especially shouldn't cast types with known properties to `AnyObject` just to the dynamically retrieve their properties using `value(forKey:)` with static keys. Simply use `Array` with the concrete type and access the properties using the dot syntax.

There's also no need for the custom conversion from `UIImage` to `CIImage` and then to `CGImage`, `UIImage` has a built in property, `cgImage` that you can use for the conversion.